# How to return a JQuery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, durandal

I have the following durendal code:

```
var variable = ko.observable("");
function activate(){
   return myModel.doSomething(variable);
}
```

`doSomething` is defined as follow:

```
function doSomething(variable){
    if(someCondition)
       return $.ajax(...).success(function(data){variable(data)});
    variable(defaultValue);
    return defaultValue;
}
```

This code works fine when `someCondition==true`, variable gets initialized with the ajax call results.
when `someCondition==false` the activate method returns without the variable being initialized.

From what I read in the documentation, the happy path works because the ajax call returns a promise but not in the `else` case.

I tried this:

```
function activate(){
   return myModel.doSomething(variable).promise();
}
```

but I get an error saying that the observable does not have a `promise` method which makes sense.

**Question**
How can I make the `else` clause return a promise just as what the ajax call does?

Comment: Do you want to immediately reject the promise as well?

Comment: It's strange that you want your `doSomething` function to return a promise in one case and a completely different type of object in another case. Normally you only do that if the second type of object is `false` or `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better encapsulate the logic inside the `doSomething` function, so it always returns a promise. You can use the `system.defer` from Durandal to achieve this:

```
var system = require('durandal/system');

function doSomething(){
       return system.defer(function(dfd){
            if (someCondition)
                return $.ajax(...).then(function (res) {
                    dfd.resolve(res);
                });
            else
                dfd.resolve(defaultValue);
        }).promise();
}
```

And then in your activate:

```
function activate(){
   return myModel.doSomething().then(function(res){
         variable(res);
     });
}
```

Notice that the variable to be updated is no loger passed to the function. The promise will always return a value, either from the AJAX call or the default one.